# libiconv missing on OSX 10.8 installing nokogiri

Tags: ruby, rubygems, nokogiri, libiconv

I know this has been asked before, but I'm struggling to get this working and a lot of gems depend on nokogiri unfortunately

I'm running 10.8.2 with rvm, ruby 1.9.3

Running the following command, obtained from various gists / stack overflow questions on the topic:
    gem install nokogiri -- --with-iconv-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.13.1

gives "libiconv is missing."

Even though looking inside that dir shows the libiconv directories.

How can I go about getting this working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are instructions at http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html which explain what's worked in the past for homebrew 0.9 users.

If those instructions don't work for you, please email nokogiri-talk and we'll figure it out and update the installation documentation.

Comment: Thanks.  I have tried to go through those instructions.  I think maybe i have done something wrong and now i'm off the path things are not looking good.  Ill email them and see if they can help out.

Comment: You guys helped me out over there. Thanks v much. Issues with macports conflicting with homebrew & other things up with my setup. Using brew doctor also helped